# Android app icon foreground defaulting to android logo

Tags: android, android-layout

I just added an icon to my app using the Android Image Asset Studio using an xml file as the foreground and a plain color as a background.  Now in the testing I've done with it, the background of the icon is displaying as the correct color, but the foreground is just the white android logo.  I have deleted the app off my phone and reinstalled it in case it was cached as the previous logo, and I don't really know what else to do with it to test it or make it show up correctly, especially since the background changed but the foreground didn't.  Any help would be appreciated.

Github link:
[www.github.com/jollygreenegiant/WannaCook](http://www.github.com/jollygreenegiant/WannaCook)

Comment: What is the resource name of the icon?

Comment: ic_launcher.  The foreground is ic_chef_white I think, it's in the drawable folder, ic_launcher is in mipmap, as generated by Android Asset Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rename your desired mipmap icon's resource into any name different form `ic_launcher`
Also make sure you changed the icon name in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're testing on API 26+ (not specified in question).

In that case, the [Adaptive Icon](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) assets found in your repo (.../res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/) are overriding the PNG icons you hoped to use. This explains why renaming your icon files would resolve the issue, as mentioned in another answer. You can simply remove those files, to correctly resolve the issue. (Or, look into creating your own adaptive icon as described at the link above.)

Answer (score -1):

Your app icon is still `mipmap/ic_launcher`, and it's foreground is set to the white android icon set by the Android Studio. You should change the code of foreground.

Comment: Open `mipmap/ic_launcher`, set the `foreground android:drawable` attribute value to `@drawable/ic_chef_white`